# Prevent an RD session from being knoced off when another RD Session tries to login

Tags: remote, desktop, rds

I would like to configure a Microsoft Server 2012 server to not log the current RD admin user out when I try to login to the same server. Only me the Admin and a developer need to access this server remotely occasionally. We both are using the same admin account. Can't this be done with gpedit? Can't find where in gpedit. This is on a domain but not the DC.

Comment: As a general practice you shouldn't be sharing accounts.  Create per-user admin accounts.

Answer (score 2):

In RD session Host configuration you can uncheck the option: limit the user to one single session in the Remote desktop Licensing Mode.